# Show there exists a differentiable function y=g(x) given an equation in x and y.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Show that there exists a differentiable function $y = g(x)$ defined in some neighborhood $(a, b)$ of $0$ that solves the equation $(y^2 + 2)\times\sin y = 2\times x^3$.
I.e., $$(g(x)^2 + 2)\times \sin g(x) = 2\times x^3$$
It is satisfied for all $x$ from the domain of $g$ and $g(0) = 0$.

Determine the derivative of this function
at $0$?

I know that it relates to the implicit function theorem but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Why did you delete and repost your question?

Comment: Because I wanted to reword the question

Comment: You can edit your question. There is no need to delete and repost it.  The wording is identical anyway (except the last sentence).

Comment: okay... This does not help me with my mathematics though smcc, but I will keep that in mind for future reference thanks

Comment: What have you tried? The question is just a direct application of the implicit function theorem. (Or you can just apply the chain rule to differentiate both sides of the equation with respect to $x$, then solve for $g'(x)$ and then evaluate at $x=0$.)

Comment: I do not understand how to apply the implicit function theorem (am I currently looking up examples of this).

Comment: Okay I get that last part. With the first part, when deriving, how should I treat g(x)? I am deriving with respect to x aren't I? So do I treat g(x) as a constant or?

Comment: What last part and what first part are you referring to? If you want to differentiate $[g(x)]^2$ (with respect to $x$) for example, you just apply the chain rule to get $2g(x)g'(x)$. More generally, the chain rule says the derivative of $f(g(x))$ is $f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $F$ be given by

$$F(x,y)=(y^2+2)\sin y-2x^3$$

By the implicit function theorem

$$g'(0)=-\frac{F_x(0,0)}{F_y(0,0)}$$

so long as $F_y(0,0)\neq 0$.

---

Alternatively, use the chain rule (and product rule) to differentiate both sides of

$$([g(x)]^2+2)\sin [g(x)]=2x^3$$

and then solve for $g'(x)$ and evaluate at $x=y=0$.

Comment: Thank you this really helped